# Remove a set of fields from a array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a native PHP function that can remove a set of keys from a array?

for eg. if I have a array like
`array('a' => 'aaa', 'b' => 'bbb', 'c' => 'ccc', 'd' => 'ddd');`

and I want to remove `'b', 'c'` and get `array('a' => 'aaa', 'd' => 'ddd');` ?

Comment: Those are values, not keys. To unset a key you would use `unset()`, but only if you know the keys to the values.

Comment: I meant keys, they have values too with `=>`, but I didn't think it was important to add them :P

Comment: @Alex: then please clarify your question, and insert the `=>`s.

Comment: @Alex: Well there is a difference. Do you have `array('a' => 'something')` or `array('something' => 'a')` ?

Comment: sorry, I updated my question :)

Comment: @Alex: we need to know: do you want to remove indices based on their key, or their value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
  if (in_array($v,array('b','c'))) unset($array[$k]);
}
```

Comment: ITYM unset($array[$k]). unset($k) does nothing.

Answer (score 10):

It's [`array_diff_key`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php).

```
$input = array(...);
$remove = array_flip(array('a', 'b')); // 'a' and 'b' are the keys to remove
$output = array_diff_key($input, $remove);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/EY6yP6)**.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `array_flip(array('a', 'b'))`?

Comment: @acme: Oops! Thanks for the catch, I added the missing `array()` and linked an example.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate to everyone else's answer, though all valid in their own way, is the [array_splice](https://www.php.net/array_splice) function.

```
$foo = Array(
  'a' => 'aaaa',
  'b' => 'bbbb',
  'c' => 'cccc',
  'd' => 'dddd'
);
var_dump($foo);
array_splice($foo, 1, 2);
var_dump($foo);
```

Which produces:

```
array(4) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(4) "aaaa"
  ["b"]=>
  string(4) "bbbb"
  ["c"]=>
  string(4) "cccc"
  ["d"]=>
  string(4) "dddd"
}
array(2) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(4) "aaaa"
  ["d"]=>
  string(4) "dddd"
}
```

Comment: +1, Good, if he knows the position of the indices, and not just the key.

Comment: @Jonah: Correct. But I think we all can agree the question is too vague for a definitive answer, just adding yet another way to skin the cat.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have too many fields to remove, you can use [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/function.unset.php):

```
unset($foo['b']);
unset($foo['c']);
var_dump($foo)
```